# Automated validation of Extractions from Intelligent Document Processing

Tags: validation, huggingface-transformers, text-extraction, information-extraction, document-processing

I'm currently working on a project that involves using [XtractEdge](https://www.edgeverve.com/xtractedge/) (which is similar to Amazon Textract, Microsoft Intelligent
Document Processing) to extract valuable information from a variety of documents. One of the major challenges I'm facing is how to effectively validate these extractions without manual intervention. I'd greatly appreciate your insights and answers into different techniques that could be employed for this validation process.

I'm particularly interested in exploring the following approaches:

1. **Consistency or Rule-Based Validation:**
   How can I develop a reliable rule-based validation system to ensure the
   consistency of extracted  information? Are there any best practices or
   tools you recommend for setting
   up such a system?
2. **Utilizing Algorithms or Statistical Methods:**
   I'm curious about integrating algorithms or statistical methods to
   validate the accuracy of the extracted data. What are some commonly used
   techniques in this area, and how can they be applied to the context of
   information extraction?
3. **Cross Verification with Other Sources:**
   Cross verification with external sources seems promising. Could you share
   your experiences with  implementing this approach? What are the potential
   challenges and benefits of comparing extracted information with data from
   other trusted sources?

If you've encountered similar challenges or have expertise in information extraction and validation, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

The idea which is revolving in my mind is to use the results extracted from any Intelligent Document Processing application (**IDP**) and use a Document Question and Answering Transformers from HuggingFace to compare the results from both the applications and validate the outputs obtained in each case. But the point where I face a hurdle is, to find the right IDP and implement a transformer in it to validate the outputs.